# finding similar elements within two arrays

Tags: r

Is there a faster way to do this? N^2 time just seems terrible.

```
mergeData<-function(p,c) {
  for(i in 1:length(p[[1]])) {
    for(k in 1:length(c[[1]])) {
      if(toString(c[[k,46]]) == toString(p[[i,1]])) {
        #Do stuff here with pairs found
        print(i)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
row1 = c[[,46]]
row2 = p[[,1]]
x = data.frame(row = row1, nr1 = c(1:len(row1)))
y = data.frame(row = row2, nr2 = c(1:len(row2)))
same_pairs = merge(x, y)[c("nr1", "nr2")]
```

In `same_pairs` you have now indeces of a rows with the same elements.

Complexity : `O(len(row1) + len(row2))`